# dynamically add input to js d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 and am trying to create a function to dynamically add a certain number of text boxes to an html form, but have not been sucessful. Here is my code. What is the issue?

```
        for (i=0;i<numLines;i++){
        var div = document.getElementById('user-input');
        div.innerHTML += '<input id="textfield_"+i type="text" value="text_"+i>';
    }
```

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="container-exp">
<div id="Stage 2">
    <center>
            <button type="button" id="show-example" value="show-example" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg example"">
            Show Example
            </button>        
    </center><br/><br/>
    <div class="col-xs-2">

    </div>
    <div id="passage"></div>
    Fill out the below with the information in the above passage. To see an example, please click the button "Show example" above.
    </div id="user-input">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" id="next" value="next" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg continue">
            Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
            </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: the `<center>` tag has been deprecated for years. What has this to do with d3? You can add these elements with d3 but you do it the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I executed it in a jsfiddle, and it created the elements. There must be some other issue.

I tried both cases where user-input element is a `<div>` as well as a `<form>`. It worked in both cases.

While we are it, and you can ignore this - You can make some modifications to the code like this:

```
var elements = "";

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  // this is what I assume what you were trying to do in the code
  elements += "<input id='textfield_" + i + "'' type='text' value='text_" + i + "''>";

  // this is cleaner way, but not supported in older browsers
  elements += `<input id='textfield_${i}' type='text' value='text_${i}'>`;
}

var div = document.getElementById('user-input');
div.innerHTML += elements;
```

Comment: thanks! I added my html file, which may be the culprit

Comment: The HTML file is incorrectly formatted. check out this jsfiddle link. I corrected the HTML and it is adding the elements. http://jsfiddle.net/jforcode/xpvt214o/619471/

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it with d3 here is an example

```js
var numlines = 10;
d3.select("#user-input").selectAll(".dummy")
  .data(d3.range(numlines))
  .enter()
  .append("input")
  .attr("id", i => `textfield_${i}`)
  .attr("type", "text")
  .attr("value", i => `text_${i}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<div id="passage"></div>
Fill out the below with the information in the above passage. To see an example, please click the button "Show example" above.
<div id="user-input">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button type="button" id="next" value="next" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg continue">
        Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```